# Visual Studio 2012 default scrollbars

Tags: visual-studio, themes, visual-studio-2012

I've tried to make my Visual Studio more beautyful, so I downloaded Son of Obsidian color scheme from [here](http://www.rickardnilsson.net/post/2012/05/20/son-of-obsidian-color-scheme-for-resharper.aspx). And then everething is okay, except scrollbars. Scrollbars are now not Visual Studio 2012 cool custom scrollbars, but Windows default scrollbars. I've tried to resel all preferences using "Import and Export options..." menu, but this won't work. Colors returned to default state, but scrollbars are the same Windows scrollbars. By the way, I'm using Dark theme. So question is how to return normal custom scrollbars back? This default are really very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a clean install if the resets are not working.

To get a clean "Son of Obsidian" or other themes that don't affect scroll bars, [go here.](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian)

Also see the [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=visual%20studio%20color%20theme%20editor&es_th=1) extension for your version of studio that lets you manage your themes.  This should get you back to default theme settings or assist in creating new default theme settings.

After that, you can tweak some hard to find *Map Mode Scroll Bar* colors in the Visual Studio 2012-13

Tools>options>Environment>FontsAndColors>TextEditor>

**Display Items:**

- Overview background
- Overview caret
- Overview collapsed region
- Overview visible